# Is there a formula to find how many games a team will play in a competition?

Tags: basketball

Suppose I am setting up a basketball league or tournament, or following one. Is there a formula to determine the number of games each individual team will play in a regular season?

How does this work for say, eleven teams in a competition?

Comment: You need to specify the format of the competition

Comment: Originally asked, this was unclear, but the edit may have changed the meaning of the question. The interpretation may be correct, but "regular season" was used in the original post. Personally, I thought the question was about scheduling a regular season for a league with 11 teams, but the question was changed to ask about tournament structure with 11 teams.

Comment: @user257138 it is still pretty broad since there are multiple types of tournament structures. Two of the popular ones have been answered by now, but there are quite a few more. It would help a lot to narrow it down further.

Comment: A season is just a tournament that takes a long time. Asking how many games will be played by each team will have the same answer for the same structure, be it round-robin or single-elimination or qualifying-pools-brackets. @user257138

Comment: The term *regular season* implies a round-robin because that's how the majority of seasons are run in every sport. What happens in the *postseason* or *finals* is a different story but that's not important for this question. @dly

Comment: @Nij I agree with a common domestic league using round robin, but you as well edited tournament into the question, which *can* use other modes (and usually does). Also a regular season in the UEFA Champions League for example is not finished with the round robin group stage.

Comment: The group stage is a double round-robin. After that is the finals. How does the regular season not finished?

Comment: @Nij Because the CL isn't concluded there. The regular CL season ends with the final (unlike NFL for example, where the regular season is exactly the round robin stage and the playoffs and super bowl are different "events").

Comment: I disagree. You can't call it regular season when it bears no resemblance to that section of competitions as the word is typically used. The finals are the finals - they're not regular season.

Comment: Then the CL has no regular season. I can live with that too.

Comment: Then UCL isn't relevant to the question, is it?

Comment: No, but what league is?

Answer (score 1):

If the competition is a single round-robin each team plays each other team once. The number of games played by each team is one less than the number of teams. For example, 11 - 1 = 10 games.

A home-and-away competition or a double round-robin repeats this. The number of games is twice that for a single round, for example 2 × 10 = 20 games.

Note that for an odd number of teams, each team will have one bye per round, adding an additional week of competition per round (assuming one game is played per week).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Nijs answer:

For a **single elimination** tournament (playoff style) the number of games are **X-1** (X being the number of participants) and **2^Y** per participant (or less - see below)

Lets say with **16** participating teams you'd have **15 games**:

- **8** games in round 1 + **4** in round 2 + **2** semi finals + **1** final = **15 games**

That calculations works as well with an odd number of teams where you'll need byes to fill the tournament tree:

- **11 teams** = **3** games (and 5 byes) + **4** games + **2** semi finals + **1** final = **10 games**
- Need to calculate the byes? Simply round up to next next Power of 2 (in this case 16) and subtract the number of teams from it: 16 - 11 = 5.

The number of games each participant has can be calculated by using the Power of 2:

- Round *up* to the next Power of 2 (2, 4, 8, 16, 32, etc.), so with 11 participants you need to calculate with 16
- For example **8 participants** = 2^3 = **3 games** per team and **16** (rounded up from 11) = 2^4 = **4 games**
- There are exceptions:

  - getting eliminated early
  - byes (with 11 teams a tournament of 16 requires 5 byes = 5 teams with one less game)